# Why is the jquery $.post command not sending JSON data to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flask

I've been using the `$.getJSON` command for awhile.  But since I'm actually posting to the server I need to be using $.post.  But as soon as I switch from `$.getJSON` to `$.post`, the back end, which is the Flask Python framework, doesn't seem receive any JSON data.  That's the only thing I changed.  The documentation for **[$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)** seems to indicate that the format is the same for sending data with either command.

With `$.getJSON`, I could access the JSON parameters in Flask with the request.args.get command.  But after changing to $.post, request.args is empty (so request.args.get() always returns None).  Here's the line of javascript with `$.getJSON`:

```
$.getJSON("/admin/emails/ajax/send", {'data':JSON.stringify(data)}, function(){...})
```

And then just imagine that line with `$.post(...)` instead.

***EDIT*** It appears that issue is when I change from 'GET' to 'POST', the data disappears from Flask's `request.args` object.  I tried using the `$.ajax` method and go the same results.  Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unwrap this beast and use $.ajax so you're not tripping over wrappers.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/admin/emails/ajax/send',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
        //the JSON response from the server
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, just this and the it does work like you have it...but when I change type:'POST' to type:'GET', then I received the JSON data.  It appears that Flask puts the 'POST' data somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out.  If you send JSON data to the server in a 'GET' method, Flask puts the JSON data into `request.args`.  If, instead, you send the data in 'POST' method, Flask puts the data in `request.form`.  Kinda confusing, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct, but if wanna use $.post u should go to server side and add a header: "Content-type: app/json"(something like this google it)

Comment: Why? Isn't that going to set the content type of the response?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `$.post` this way:

```
$.post("/admin/emails/ajax/send", {'data':JSON.stringify(data)}, function(data){
   console.log(data);
}, "json");
//-^^^^^^-----------are you putting dataType here.
```

Comment: That parameter specifies the expected type of the _response_. OP's problem is that the server-side code can't access the data in the _request_.